# Try-catch every line of code without individual try-catch blocks

Tags: c#, try-catch, expression-trees

**I do not currently have this issue**, but you never know, and thought experiments are always fun.

**Ignoring the obvious problems that you would have to have with your architecture to even be attempting this**, let's assume that you had some horribly-written code of someone else's design, and you needed to do a bunch of wide and varied operations in the same code block, e.g.:

```
WidgetMaker.SetAlignment(57);
contactForm["Title"] = txtTitle.Text;
Casserole.Season(true, false);
((RecordKeeper)Session["CasseroleTracker"]).Seasoned = true;
```

Multiplied by a hundred.  Some of these might work, others might go badly wrong.  What you need is the C# equivalent of "on error resume next", otherwise you're going to end up copying and pasting try-catches around the many lines of code.

How would you attempt to tackle this problem?

Comment: on error resume next is of the devil.

Comment: I'll second that. You really want to bite the bullet and get that mess straightened out. On Error / resume Next will allow the "known" issues through, but it will also allow any new issues through, and you'd have no idea at all. Bad news.

Comment: I love how no one actually answers the question. but rather tries to give the 'right' way. its obvious he didnt want that. Gotta have soime trust in people that they know what they are doing sometimes, especially when the it was stated the way it was, sheesh.

Comment: What's he's proposing isn't possible for one. The below solution won't work since it's going to break the scoping of variables.

Comment: Thats funny! So the next time someone asks, "hey, how can I code a memory leak?" Everyone should just explain it and not advise against it? Also, since he mainly asked "how would YOU attempt to tackle this problem?" Sounds like he's asking for opinion.

Comment: You guys are brilliant.  I'm asking "what should I do if I ever find myself hanging off a cliff" and your answer is "you shouldn't ever hang off a cliff".  Ignore the point why don't you!

Comment: That's not what they're saying. You're asking how do I use X tool to get off the cliff and they're saying X tool will get you killed. Use Y tool instead.

Comment: No Cristopher columbus, Dont sail that far you will fall off the edge of the world!

Comment: Try/Catching is a tool in your toolbelt. So is rewriting the code so that it works. Try/catch here is almost garunteed to make the situation worse. Rewriting the code has a much higher likelihood of success.

Comment: That's possibly true, but if I don't have time to copy and paste several hundred try-catches or do a quick regex, I'm not going to have time to use "Y tool" and rewrite the entire application, am I?  Can you see how it would then be useful just to put "on error resume next" at the top?

Comment: The complexity of the code you would have to write in order to successfully automate the task of try/catch will make your heart weep. It really would be an insane undertaking as you would have to adjust for way too many factors.

Comment: Hey, Lets drop this bull$$$$. I htink we all know that. Geeze. You dont need to get all freaking code guru on me. Look at how the question was posed. Forget the How would you tackle, it was How would you tackle it in the context the question was given. If you woulnt, thats fine. dont post.

Comment: Guys, can we please refrain from having some flamewar here, the OP has clearly stated they know the architecture is borked, if you want to answer, answer, if not, go to another question.

Comment: You are right. i just want to apologize here to orion. I know you were trying to to answer the the 'right' way, the way you would tackle it personally, where as I was looking at it as tackling it as an on error continue. I Wasnt trying to say you were wrong, but maybe I came across as that.

Comment: You can always downvote the question if you don't like how it is. :D

Comment: of course. And thats why i upvoted it and downvoted others who couldnt seem to understand the context of the question :)

Comment: I too apologize if I came off harshly. But I feel this site as designed is to not simply ask questions and get answers, but is intended to improve the overall knowledge of its users with regard to programming. As such I'm not sure what value the question has, but I've added my own take below.

Comment: as well i added another post here below.

Comment: Seems the question had a lot of uses. For one - hopefully vbers will stop using the 'On error screw it and hope for the best' statement to make up for not wanting to understand error handling!

Comment: The OP clearly stated he knew that it wasn't the best code to use, but wanted a solution for that particular situation. If someone asks you how to code a 'memory leak', asking if they know what it means is OK ofcourse.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's pretty obvious that you'd write the code in VB.NET, which actually does have [On Error Resume Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as.aspx), and export it in a DLL to C#. Anything else is just being a glutton 
 for punishment.

Comment: I do believe that this is a valid solution which solves the puzzle posed in the question, so I am accepting the answer!

Answer (score 47):

```
public delegate void VoidDelegate();

public static class Utils
{
  public static void Try(VoidDelegate v) {
    try {
      v();
    }
    catch {}
  }
}

Utils.Try( () => WidgetMaker.SetAlignment(57) );
Utils.Try( () => contactForm["Title"] = txtTitle.Text );
Utils.Try( () => Casserole.Season(true, false) );
Utils.Try( () => ((RecordKeeper)Session["CasseroleTracker"]).Seasoned = true );
```

Comment: This makes the most sense, really.

Comment: As of .net 3.5, you can use Action instead of voidDelegate.

Comment: I love this! This is like getting the @ operator from PHP in C#.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php  And I don't have to write this question.

Comment: How come Action works here also even if you start passing parameters? Is the compiler handling this for you... like ignoring or dropping the params?

Comment: As David B said, Action would be better

Comment: @B. Tyndall - the Action doesn't take the parameters; they are passed via a thing called a "closure"

Comment: The major problem here is the "catch {}" which will catch things that should never be caught, including low-level errors in the state of the CLR.

Comment: @Daniel, it will but only in the context of the delegate.  The scope is limited to the function being called.

Comment: @Andrew Neely - The problem I referred to is nothing to do with catching errors elsewhere in the program. It is just that it catches too many errors that might occur during the execution of the delegate alone. e.g. `NullReferenceException`, `ArgumentException` and many other things that should never be swallowed and ignored.

Comment: @Daniel, I understand, and agree.  My point was this would limit the catch to a specific line, a line for which he was wanting to say "I don't care if the following line throws an exception, ignore it."  In that context, how is masking an exception a problem, other than the fact it's a really bad idea.  The bad idea part, though, was established in the question itself.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @brun Kind of late here, but there are 17 declarations of Action, each taking 0-16 parameters.

Comment: I know, I'm a bit late to the party, however I wanted to add a legitimate case here: When I shutdown a service or define a destructor, where several events have to be unsubscribed or you have no way to check prior to an exception, I may want to do this shutdown process gracefully, even if some of the statements fail. Of course, this is not good for general purpose, still, and one has to be careful with things that depend on each other along the codepiece. The approach in this answer looks best to me, although I'd rather call it something like `JustCatch` to make the catching behavior clearer.

Answer (score 22):

Refactor into individual, well-named methods:

```
AdjustFormWidgets();
SetContactTitle(txtTitle.Text);
SeasonCasserole();
```

Each of those is protected appropriately.

Answer (score 20):

I would say **do nothing**.

Yup thats right, do NOTHING.

You have clearly identified two things to me:

1. You know the architecture is borked.
2. There is a ton of this crap.

I say:

- Do nothing.
- Add a global error handler to send you an email every time it goes boom.
- Wait until something falls over (or fails a test)
- Correct that (Refactoring as necessary **within the scope of the page**).
- Repeat every time a problem occurs.

You will have this cleared up in no time if it is that bad. Yeah I know it sounds sucky and you may be pulling your hair out with bugfixes to begin with, but it will allow you to **fix the needy/buggy code before** the (large) amount of **code that may actually be working** no matter how crappy it looks.

Once you start winning the war, you will have a better handle on the code (due to all your refactoring) you will have a better idea for a winning design for it..

Trying to wrap all of it in bubble wrap is probably going to take just a long to do and you will still not be any closer to fixing the problems.

Comment: my exact method on umpteen projects - great explanation

Answer (score 8):

This is one of the things that having a preprocessor is useful for.  You could define a macro that swallows exceptions, then with a quick script add that macro to all lines.

So, if this were C++, you could do something like this:

```
#define ATTEMPT(x) try { x; } catch (...) { }
// ...
ATTEMPT(WidgetMaker.SetAlignment(57));
ATTEMPT(contactForm["Title"] = txtTitle.Text);
ATTEMPT(Casserole.Season(true, false));
ATTEMPT(((RecordKeeper)Session["CasseroleTracker"]).Seasoned = true);
```

Unfortunately, not many languages seem to include a preprocessor like C/C++ did.

You could create your own preprocessor and add it as a pre-build step.  If you felt like completely automating it you could probably write a preprocessor that would take the actual code file and add the try/catch stuff in on its own (so you don't have to add those ATTEMPT() blocks to the code manually).  Making sure it only modified the lines it's supposed to could be difficult though (have to skip variable declarations, loop constructs, etc to that you don't break the build).

However, I think these are horrible ideas and should never be done, but the question was asked. :)

Really, you shouldn't ever do this.  You need to find what's causing the error and fix it.  Swallowing/ignoring errors is a bad thing to do, so I think the *correct* answer here is "Fix the bug, don't ignore it!". :)

Comment: Hey, someone who actually answers the question, you got my vote ;)

Comment: The problem is this still wouldn't work as intended, at least not without some additional thinking.

If you do this then it's almost garunteed you're going to move variables out of scope and break your build.

Comment: That's why I said you need to be careful to skip variable declarations, along with other things.

Comment: Even if you don't break your build, which would be hard, there's a ton of stuff to actually look for beyond just variable declarations and looping constructs. I know you're suggesting he actually go through with it (quite the contrary).

Comment: But that's just what makes trying to write a tool for this fun!  (or incredibly painful). :)

Answer (score 8):

### [Fail Fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast)

To elaborate, I guess I am questioning the question. If an exception is thrown, why would you want your code to simply continue as if nothing has happened? Either you expect exceptions in certain situations, in which case you write a try-catch block around that code and handle them, or there is an unexpected error, in which case you should prefer your application to abort, or retry, or fail. Not carry on like a wounded zombie moaning 'brains'.

Comment: Wiki link "answers" are really not that helpful.. Why not try expanding on this?

Answer (score 7):

`On Error Resume Next` is a really bad idea in the C# world. Nor would adding the equivalent to `On Error Resume Next` actually help you. All it would do is leave you in a bad state which could cause more subtle errors, data loss and possibly data corruption.

But to give the questioner his due, you could add a global handler and check the TargetSite to see which method borked. Then you could at least know what line it borked on. The next part would be to try and figure out how to set the "next statement" the same way the debugger does it. Hopefully your stack won't have unwound at this point or you can re-create it, but it's certainly worth a shot. However, given this approach the code would have to run in Debug mode every time so that you would have your debug symbols included.

Answer (score 4):

As someone mentioned, VB allows this. How about doing it the same way in C#? Enter trusty reflector:

This:

```
Sub Main()
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Dim y As Integer = CInt(5 / i)


End Sub
```

Translates into this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // This item is obfuscated and can not be translated.
    int VB$ResumeTarget;
    try
    {
        int VB$CurrentStatement;
    Label_0001:
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
        int VB$ActiveHandler = -2;
    Label_0009:
        VB$CurrentStatement = 2;
        int i = 0;
    Label_000E:
        VB$CurrentStatement = 3;
        int y = (int) Math.Round((double) (5.0 / ((double) i)));
        goto Label_008F;
    Label_0029:
        VB$ResumeTarget = 0;
        switch ((VB$ResumeTarget + 1))
        {
            case 1:
                goto Label_0001;

            case 2:
                goto Label_0009;

            case 3:
                goto Label_000E;

            case 4:
                goto Label_008F;

            default:
                goto Label_0084;
        }
    Label_0049:
        VB$ResumeTarget = VB$CurrentStatement;
        switch (((VB$ActiveHandler > -2) ? VB$ActiveHandler : 1))
        {
            case 0:
                goto Label_0084;

            case 1:
                goto Label_0029;
        }
    }
    catch (object obj1) when (?)
    {
        ProjectData.SetProjectError((Exception) obj1);
        goto Label_0049;
    }
Label_0084:
    throw ProjectData.CreateProjectError(-2146828237);
Label_008F:
    if (VB$ResumeTarget != 0)
    {
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very funny :):) Given the very nature of this question, I would recommend the original poster to implement this approach as soon as he faces the problem - it is the closest to his question. It is the same as the accepted answer (do it in VB and use on error resume next) and it is in C#. And I would also recommend him to face the rage of someone having to maintain this after him. It is about the mindset...you either want to try-catch every line of a thousand lines long method, or you refactor that method and make the whole thing better. No what-if thought experimeents needed.

Comment: @Marek, refactoring is a great objective, however there are times that you have to keep the whole mess running while you overhaul it.  Users hate it when they lose data because of an unhandled exception closes the application.  They don't point to the fool who wrote made the mess, but at the developer now responsible.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the code.  Try to find sets of statements which logically depend on each other, so that if one fails then the next ones make no sense, and hive them off into their own functions and put try-catches round them, if you want to ignore the result of that and continue.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you in identifing the pieces that have the most problems.

@ JB King
Thanks for reminding me. The Logging application block has a Instrumentation Event that can be used to trace events, you can find more info on the MS Enterprise library docs.

```
Using (New InstEvent)
<series of statements> 
End Using
```

All of the steps in this using will be traced to a log file, and you can parse that out to see where the log breaks (ex is thrown) and id the high offenders.

Refactoring is really your best bet, but if you have a lot, this may help you pinpoint the  worst offenders.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the compiler to give you an expression tree for this code, then you could modify that expression tree by replacing each statement with a new try-catch block that wraps the original statement.  This isn't as far-fetched as it sounds; for LINQ, C# acquired the ability to capture lambda expressions as expression trees that can be manipulated in user code at runtime.

This approach is not possible today with .NET 3.5 -- if for no other reason than the lack of a "try" statement in System.Linq.Expressions. However, it may very well be viable in a future version of C# once the merge of the DLR and LINQ expression trees is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use goto, but it's still messy.

I've actually wanted a sort of single statement try-catch for a while.  It would be helpful in certain cases, like adding logging code or something that you don't want to interrupt the main program flow if it fails.

I suspect something could be done with some of the features associated with linq, but don't really have time to look into it at the moment.  If you could just find a way to wrap a statement as an anonymous function, then use another one to call that within a try-catch block it would work... but not sure if that's possible just yet.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the reflection in c#? You could create a class that reflects on the code and use line #s as the hint for what to put in each individual try/catch block. This has a few advantages:

1. Its slightly less ugly as it doesn't really you require mangle your source code and you can use it only during debug modes.
2. You learn something interesting about c# while implementing it.

I however would recommend against any of this, unless of course you are taking over maintance of someelses work and you need to get a handle on the exceptions so you can fix them. Might be fun to write though.

Comment: fun is always good. Glad to see some more people's insite into this.

Answer (score 1):

Fun question; very terrible.

It'd be nice if you could use a macro. But this is blasted C#, so you might solve it with some preprocessor work or some external tool to wrap your lines in individual try-catch blocks. Not sure if you meant you didn't want to *manually* wrap them or that you wanted to avoid try-catch *entirely*.

Messing around with this, I tried labeling every line and jumping back from a single catch, without much luck. However, [Christopher uncovered the correct way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117173/c-try-catch-every-line-of-code-without-individual-try-catch-blocks#118742). There's some [interesting additional discussion of this at Dot Net Thoughts](http://dotnetthoughts.wordpress.com/2007/10/12/why-language-is-important-why-i-prefer-c/) and at [Mike Stall's .NET Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2008/04/12/codegen-for-on-error-resume-next.aspx).

*EDIT: Of course. The `try-catch` / `switch-goto` solution listed won't actually compile since the `try` labels are out-of-scope in `catch`. Anyone know what's missing to make something like this compile?*

You could automate this with a compiler preprocess step or maybe hack up [Mike Stall's Inline IL tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/02/21/377806.aspx) to inject some error-ignorance.

([Orion Adrian's answer about examining the Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117173/c-try-catch-every-line-of-code-without-individual-try-catch-blocks#117202) and trying to set the next instruction is interesting too.)

All in all, it seems like an interesting and instructive exercise. Of course, you'd have to decide at what point the effort to simulate ON ERROR RESUME NEXT outweighs the effort to fix the code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Catch the errors in the [UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) of the application. That way, unhandled execptions can even be logged as to the sender and whatever other information the developer would reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are probably out of luck. On Error Resume Next is a legacy option that is generally heavily discouraged, and does not have an equivalent to my knowledge in C#.

I would recommend leaving the code in VB (It sounds like that was the source, given your specific request for OnError ResumeNext) and interfacing with or from a C# dll or exe that implements whatever new code you need. Then preform refactoring to cause the code to be safe, and convert this safe code to C# as you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at integrating the Enterprise Library's Exception Handling component for one idea of how to handle unhandled exceptions.

If this is for ASP.Net applications, there is a function in the Global.asax called, "Application_Error" that gets called in most cases with catastrophic failure being the other case usually.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Lost Plugin Writer, I'd like to share a shorter alternative solution for several actions:

```
public static class Utils
{
  public static void JustCatchEach(params Action[] actions)
  {
    if (actions == null || actions.Length == 0)
      return;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < actions.Length; i++)
      try { actions[i]?.Invoke(); } catch { }
  }
  
  // this one is for illustration purposes below
  public static void SomeVoidMethod() { }
}
```

and call it with:

```
Utils.JustCatchEach(
  () => WidgetMaker.SetAlignment(57),
  () => contactForm["Title"] = txtTitle.Text,
  () => Casserole.Season(true, false),
  () => ((RecordKeeper)Session["CasseroleTracker"]).Seasoned = true,
  
  // you can give it a simple void method like this:
  () => Utils.SomeVoidMethod(),
  // or like this:
  Utils.SomeVoidMethod
  );
```

Just to be clear, this is still inherently not good practice in general, as it has been discussed here already. While this may be useful in complicated graceful shutdowns like in destructors or in `IDisposable.Dispose()` or similar, you should never need to use this anywhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Ignoring all the reasons you'd want to avoid doing this.......

If it were simply a need to keep # of lines down, you could try something like:

```
int totalMethodCount = xxx;
for(int counter = 0; counter < totalMethodCount; counter++) {
    try {
        if (counter == 0) WidgetMaker.SetAlignment(57);
        if (counter == 1) contactForm["Title"] = txtTitle.Text;
        if (counter == 2) Casserole.Season(true, false);
        if (counter == 3) ((RecordKeeper)Session["CasseroleTracker"]).Seasoned = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // log here
    }
}
```

However, you'd have to keep an eye on variable scope if you try to reuse any of the results of the calls.

Answer (score -7):

Hilite each line, one at a time, 'Surround with' try/catch. That avoids the copying pasting you mentioned

Comment: This doesn't actually work. You'll break scoping.

int i;

i = 5;

can't be try catch'ed.

Comment: What the hell are you talking about? Where in the heck was there any variable assignment in the posters question?

Comment: The implication was that it was "times 100" meaning that there's a lot of code there that wasn't presented. In that case then there's bound to be a variable assignment or two along with the dozen or so other constructs that can't be try/catch'ed singly.

Comment: 100 X those four lines of code still presents ZERO assignments.

Comment: His code has a "e.g." We're both assuming what the rest of the code looks like. It could be all the same at which point it could be easily refactored into methods or you could be right and then the ATTEMPT() thing above could work.

Comment: Its all ABout context man. THIS POST was OBVIOUSLY not an attempt at aquiring the code guru uber pattern way of doing it. I think that was VERY clear! Maybe I am special because I could see that in the question. Maybe you are special because you can see beyond the code sample that was given. I dunno

Comment: regardless I wont be back on this thread as its degenerated into nothingness.

Comment: @mattlant I would give you +1 for funniest answer in this thread, but I am afraid that you are being serious :):):)