# C# XMl Deserialisation with non existing Paths

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization, xsd.exe

I've with xsd.exe created the class for my XML. In the XML (SEPA camt.053) are multiply nested Nodes that have minOccurs = 0.

I navigate to the node like this:

```
entry.NtryDtls[0].TxDtls[0].RltdPties.CdtrAcct.Id.Item
```

In this Path RltdPties, CdtrAcct and Id could be null.

If RltdPties is null I get an Exception, because CdtrAcct doesn't exist.

Is there an easy way without checking each node if it is null to get the Value of Item?
If path doesn't exist it would be enough to get null (or something else) from the last node that I can check.

My idea is to surround this query with try/catch and if it throws an Exception I can set the Variable to an empty string or so.

Comment: NtryDtls? Is that supposed to mean 'Entry Details?' I would consider revising those variable names because I struggled to read it and others will too.

Comment: Someone already answered in here, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298009/ignore-nullreferenceexception-when-reading-object-properties

Comment: The Nodes names are not from me. It's defined by iso 20022 / SEPA camt.053 format. But after a week with this xml file I don't see these abbreviations. 

thanks for the link. I hoped that there is an easy way to this because of this deep xml structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer is no. You have to check for a null reference before invoking methods or operators upon members.

Comment: I hoped for a way that's easier, so i have to check every object in this path.