# Looking for an automated logging tool/library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, logging, error-handling

I'm looking for an library/tool for .NET that logs almost everything that happens in my C# application (Windows Form).

The problem is that I'm delivering an application to a client (Windows XP) and after doing some task, that classic Microsoft error window appears:

> "*ApplicationName* has encountered a
>   problem and needs to close. We are
>   sorry for the inconvenience"

I'm currently handling my application exceptions, but this is something external and I can't get anything from that error, so I would like any automated library that helps me with that.

It would work if it logs each line of code executed, orr just log what line was executing before that error appeared, or something that could give me more info about that error.

*P.S*: It's a multithreaded application, and have to Timer controls (one for watching a folder every 5secs, and another for watching thread list...). I'm using Windows 7 here and everything seems to work ok.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a magic library.

Comment: Maybe I am, but sometimes I don't think I'm going to find a 'magic' library and I finally do ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "something external"?  Did you check the Event Viewer on the client's machine?  Maybe it will show that the CLR itself has crashed, like the famous "Fatal execution engine error".  In this case, none of your logging will help, unless you just happen to log enough of the magic steps to reproduce the error on your dev system.

Comment: Log *each line of code executed?* That log would fill up your hard drive very quickly and bring the program to a standstill.  Even logging each *method* is prohibitively expensive.  Exceptions already produce a stack trace and that *ought* to be enough.

Comment: I think a mod should be inspecting the DV's on this post as it seems as someone is specifically DV'ing all answers perhaps in an attempt to legitimatize their commercial product more than the other answers. The number of DV's in this post seem to be very high for relevant answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not log in the windows event viewer, that's what it's made for. From a simple config setting you can toggle it to include all levels under, for example,  4- Verbose, 3- Information, 2-warning, 1-Error, you just log the message as one of these 4 types. You can also combine this with a boolean traceswitch for debug tracing, but it's not necessary.

The windows event viewer also offers you summaries, can be connected to remotely, and sysadmins are comfortable in working with it.

```
using System;
```

using System.Diagnostics;

class MySample{

```
public static void Main(){

    // Create the source, if it does not already exist.
    if(!EventLog.SourceExists("MySource")){
        EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource", "MyNewLog");
        Console.WriteLine("CreatingEventSource");
    }

    // Create an EventLog instance and assign its source.
    EventLog myLog = new EventLog();
    myLog.Source = "MySource";

    // Write an informational entry to the event log.    
    myLog.WriteEntry("Writing to event log.");

}
```

}

Sounds like what you need is to put a breakpoint and step through your code, if it's threaded, just open the thread windows in visual studio while stepping through the code. Temporarily put longer delays on your timers if to many threads make it difficult to debug.

Comment: Based on the phrasing of the question, I'm not sure using the windows event viewer is ideal for the level of verbosity that he is going to log to. There are limits to the sizes of the windows event log, and depending on how it's configured, hitting those limits can cause some major problems. Also, since this is running on client computers, exporting and obtaining a copy of event lots is not very ideal. However, with log4net, saving it to the event log IS an option, just not one I would recommend.

Comment: Certainly a lot of logging needs to be done during development, or even debugging in prodocution, but that is temporary and you often clear your event log to start fresh, admins know how to configure it and don't need to call you for it. In production it shouldnt be set to verbose, I don't see the point of showing every method name in the log... infact managed code, in production, should be obfuscated and the method names hidden.

Also you could consider this ETW in .Net4.0, also used for logging and new. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264810(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you're going to find a logging tool that you just plug in and it logs every single thing that happens. You're going to have to plug into the hooks that any logging framework out there has. [Here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is a popular, and free, one.

Comment: @Jaxidian: Thanks for your reply. I'll test log4net and will let you know ;)

Answer (score 2):

With ideas from
[C#: Try-catch every line of code without individual try-catch blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117173/c-try-catch-every-line-of-code-without-individual-try-catch-blocks)

I have created a class like this:

```
public delegate void VoidDelegate();
public static class L
{
    public static void g(VoidDelegate v)
    {
        DateTime now1, now2;
        StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(true);

        now1 = DateTime.Now;
        v();
        now2 = DateTime.Now;

        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\L.g", 
            now1.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff") + "\t" +
            trace.GetFrame(1).GetFileName() + ":" + trace.GetFrame(1).GetFileLineNumber() + "\t" +
            (now2 - now1).Seconds.ToString() + ((now2 - now1).Milliseconds / 1000f).ToString().Substring(1) + 
            Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

To apply logs, you may add

```
L.g(() =>/**/
```

and

```
/**/);
```

to every possible lines, e.g.

```
string[] sAryArg = null;
L.g(() =>/**/sAryArg = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()/**/);
L.g(() =>/**/this.lblUserName.Text = sAryArg[3]/**/);
L.g(() =>/**/this.lblDatabase.Text = DbUtil._sEnvID_/**/);
L.g(() =>/**/this.lblVersion.Text =
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.Major.ToString() + "." +
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.Minor.ToString() + "." +
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.Build.ToString()/**/);
```

The resulting log file will be look like this:

> 2012/02/29 10:41:18.1835418 D:\xxx\frmMain.cs:351 0.015
>
> 2012/02/29 10:41:18.1991666 D:\xxx\frmMain.cs:352 1.203

To disable the logs, simply batch remove the two surrounding tags.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you will get regarding your requirement ("logs almost everything that happens in my C# application") is to use a logging framework with AOP support and automated exception handling. Aspect oriented programming will allow you to instrument your methods and trace method execution. Together with a logging tool such as [SmartInspect](https://www.gurock.com/smartinspect) (disclaimer: I'm one of the developers behind SmartInspect) you can monitor and analyze the method execution and view exceptions in context (see screenshot below).

To log your application data and events, you will have to instrument your code manually, there's really no way around it. If you have a large application, manually instrumenting all of your code at once won't work (it's just too time consuming), so I generally recommend starting with your most critical routines and modules first.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gurock.com](http://www.gurock.com/images/feature/smartinspect-screenshot.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ETW? ETW is the fastest and the least overhead logging system in windows. ETW is built into Kernel. MS uses ETW for every application they build ,from Windows to VS.NET.

This is not a automated logging tool. But will give you stack-trace of every call in your application without you having to modifying your code. If you need add custom logging messages then you would have write code for this.

Here are some of the links for [ETW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163437.aspx) and I also have few posts on [ETW in managed code](http://naveensrinivasan.com/etw/)

Answer (score -2):

I've used [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) in the past. You can just wire it up so anytime an uncaught exception occurs, it is logged to a file, or written to the database.

Comment: I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial)
 that demonstrate ho to use it on Code Project
and and here is a [full video](https://youtu.be/2lAdQ_QwNww) on YouTube also

Answer (score -2):

Try to log your exception in window event viewer with different entry level. Check sample code from MSDN http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307024